# Invalid bitcode version for archiving iOS app

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, stripe-payments, bitcode

When I try to `Archive` my app in Xcode 11.2.1 it returns the error:

I have previously worked on the app with the beta version of Xcode 13.

I have tried to turn `Enable Bitcode` to `No` but that did not fix the problem.

I get an error in the Stripe Cocoapod:

`ld: could not reparse object file in bitcode bundle: 'Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '1103.0.32.62.0_0' Reader: '1100.0.33.12_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 11.0.0, (clang-1100.0.33.12)' for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stripe CocoaPod was built with [Xcode 11.5 or 11.6](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/XcodeVersionInfo). Three options:

- Upgrade to at least Xcode 11.5.
- Ask Stripe to support Xcode 11.2.1
- Change the Podfile to use an older version of Stripe.